# Renaming multiple folders by stripping a known prefix, also if folder names contain whitespaces

Tags: bash, directory, rename, prefix

I'm about to move some IMAP accounts to another server. The old server was setup to add the prefix .INBOX. to each folder, but not the new one . So I tried to rename all folders, stripping the .INBOX. prefixes.

What I did in bash:

```
for name in .INBOX.*;
do
newname="$(echo "$name" | cut -c8-)";
mv '$name' '$newname';
done
```

But this script did only rename such folders which didn't contain whitespaces. The ones with whitespaces lead into error messages.

What's the trick?

Comment: `mv "$name" "$newname"` ?

Comment: Yeah, you've got right! After changing the single quotes into double quotes for the vars $name and $newname it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quotation. In my example below I prefer to use `while read`

Example

```
$ ls -l *.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ftpcpl ftpcpl 0 Jul 24 11:36 hello and goodbye.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ftpcpl ftpcpl 0 Jul 24 11:36 hello.txt
$ echo "hello.txt" > lista.txt
$ echo "hello and goodbye.txt" >> lista.txt
$ more lista.txt
hello.txt
hello and goodbye.txt
$ while IFS= read -r file; do mv -- "$file" "$file".new ; done < lista.txt
$ ls -l *.new
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ftpcpl ftpcpl 0 Jul 24 11:36 hello and goodbye.txt.new
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ftpcpl ftpcpl 0 Jul 24 11:36 hello.txt.new
$
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was the single quotes instead doubled ones. But your example will also do the job.